# Select Query Based on a Union Query giving error

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, union

I have a Union Query as such

```
SELECT ActivityName, IEXDate As DayOff, Format([IEXAmt], "Short Time") As AmtTime
FROM Qry_AttendanceIEX

UNION ALL 

SELECT ActivityName, CallInDate, Format([CalledAmt], "Short Time")
FROM Qry_AttendanceCallin

ORDER BY ActivityName;
```

It works perfectly.

I then have a Select Query that I am asking it to Sum the AmtTime field. I am getting a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression". The data types are the same, both Short Date and there is no criteria in the select query. Here is the SQL for the Select Query

```
SELECT Sum(Qry_AttendanceRep.AmtTime) AS SumOfAmtTime
FROM Qry_AttendanceRep;
```

I am using Access 2016

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Format function results in a string value. Can't Sum strings. Edit question to provide examples of data in IEXAmt and CalledAmt fields.

Comment: Try converting to date fields `SELECT Sum(CDate(Qry_AttendanceRep.AmtTime)) AS SumOfAmtTime
FROM Qry_AttendanceRep;`

Comment: Or possible even better for your `time` needs: `SELECT Sum(TimeValue(Qry_AttendanceRep.AmtTime)) AS SumOfAmtTime FROM Qry_AttendanceRep;`